# How to prevent the user from entering more than one character in the below sample code?

Tags: c++

I am facing problem in the below code. If the user enter more than one charater then my loop gets executed number of times equal to the length of the string entered by the user. My code is written in GNU c/c++ compiler.

Thanks in advance.

```
int continue_option()
{
    char c;
        loop:
        fflush(stdin);
                cin.ignore();
        cout<<"\n\n\t\t\t\tPress (Y/y) - Continue / Press (N/n) - Exit :";
                cin>>c;
        if(c=='y'||c=='Y')
        {
                          system("clear");
                   }
        else if(c=='n'|| c=='N') 
        {
            exit(0);
        }
        else
            {
                printf("\n\t\t\t\tInvalid Option.Try Again.....");
                                goto loop;
                        }
        fflush(stdin);
}
```

Comment: some formatting in your code would improve readability...

Comment: I'm not saying that `goto` and labels are always wrong, but do you **really** need them here ?!

Comment: C doesn't have `cin`. Don't claim you're writing C if you're not. (removing tag).

Answer (score 3):

First thing, don't use jumps. They are old style, and they make Dijkstra spin in his grave, on top of all the other bad consequences. I don't mean "vintage", I really mean old in the bad sense.

As of your question, I'd rather put the result in a std::string and only consider the first character in there:

```
std::string input;
std::cin >> input;
switch (input[0]) {
case 'y':
case 'Y':
    //your code
    break;
case 'n':
case 'N':
    exit(0);
default:
    std::cout << "Invalid text" << std::endl;
}
```

I would also refrain from using exit(), I'd rather rely on a function's return value to finally cause a return 0; in the main(), or some equivalent technique.

Comment: One technique I've used in a number of applications is that you `throw n` to terminate with return code `n`.  In main, of course, everything is wrapped in a `try { ... } catch ( int i ) { return i; }` block.

Comment: There is a problem with this however. What if the user enters "Yellow". This will still accept the string because it starts with a Y.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `cin.get()` or `getch()` to read just one character at a time. Also, I guess you'd be better off replacing the whole thing with a simple loop like:

```
char ch = '\0';
do
{
   ch = getch();
}while((tolower(ch) != 'y') || (tolower(ch) != 'n'))

if(tolower(ch) == 'y')
{
   //additional handling
}
else
{
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: getch() is platform-specific.

Comment: @King_DuckZ: Yes. I guess there will be issues with `exit(0)` as well. But I guess if OP is using this for a learning/example program, I guess this would suffice.

Comment: You have the solution to that getch() problem written in the first line, use it. :P

Comment: Again. I can enter "Yellow" and I'm pretty sure it would work even though it is not yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop the user from typing more than one character.

What you can do is ignore the rest of the line. You have already use `cin.ignore()` which ignores one character. You can use `cin.ignore(large number)` to ignore up to the large number or the end-of-line, whichever appears first.

Unlike flushing output files, `fflush(stdin)` doesn't really do anything.

Comment: I don't agree. While you're not wrong you're not right. You see what I'd do is allow them to enter a string. After doing that make sure that string[1] is null. If it's not null prompt again. Repeat until user gets the message.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the same behavior, but should put you on track:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

bool is_valid_answer(char c)
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case 'y':
        case 'Y':
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}

bool continue_option()
{
    std::cout << "Press (Y/y) to continue, (N/n) to exit: " << std::flush;

    char c = '\0';

    while (std::cin.get(c) && !is_valid_answer(c));

    return ((c == 'y') || (c == 'Y'));
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Continue option: " << continue_option() << std::endl;
}
```